# Akka HTTP, Spray Json and Option Fields Failing as Required

Tags: scala, akka-http, spray-json

I have a case class:

```
case class OpcTagPlaybook(name: String, tags: Seq[OpcTagAtTime], looped: Boolean, enabled: Option[String])
```

With an optional enabled field that will contain a date.
Spray Json describes encoding/decoding:

```
implicit val opcTagPlaybookFormat = jsonFormat4(OpcTagPlaybook)
```

And a route in akka http:

```
post {
  entity(as[OpcTagPlaybook]) { playbook =>
    val playbookCreated: Future[_] =
      (opcTagPlaybookActor ? UpsertPlaybook(playbook))
    onSuccess(playbookCreated) { _ =>
      log.info("Created playbook [{}]", playbook.name)
      complete((StatusCodes.Created, "ok"))
    }
  }
})
```

For some reason posting without the createdAt field fails:

Posting:

```
{"name": "test1",
"tags":[{"offset": 100, "tag": "hello", "value": "yo"}],
"looped": true
}
```

Fails:

```
The request content was malformed:
Object is missing required member 'enabled'
```

And if I post created it gives me another error:

```
 {"name": "test1",
 "tags":[{"offset": 100, "tag": "hello", "value": "yo"}],
 "looped": true,
 "enabled": "2018-08-08"
 }
```

gives

```
The request content was malformed:
spray.json.JsString cannot be cast to scala.Option
```

I'm assuming this is some interplay between akka http and so I'm going to just deal with the input more manually but I'd just like to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: It probably can't find a default decoder for `Option[String]`. [Try by writing it and see what happens](https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-other-types).

Comment: I think, it's more convenient to use default one from `DefaultJsonProtocol` (import or extend), then writing custom decoder.

Comment: Why don't u cast your return type to a playbook, like ``` (opcTagPlaybookActor ? UpsertPlaybook(playbook)).map to[PlayBook]``` by doing this, you are sure that your implicit json format defined will parse it to json

Comment: hitting the same issue